# Nginx rewrite query on index path

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, rule

I am trying to convert

```
/?q=bla+bla
```

to

```
/bla-bla
```

So i  have tryied this code but no succes. Error 500

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /?q=$1 last;
}
```

I need some help please. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
location = / {
    return 302 /$arg_q;
}
```